# Grails - filter declared properties from those that mixin seem to add

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm trying to create a mixin that transforms objects into some other type using using their properties. The mixin looks something like,

```
class MyMixin {

    MyModel transform() {
        MyModel model = new MyModel()
        this.properties.each { key, value ->
            model.addToList(key, value)
        }
        return model
    }

}
```

Sample usage,

```
@Mixin(MyMixin)
class OtherModel {

   Integer number
   String description

}
```

However, it seems like some properties are getting added under the hood. When I test the number of entries added to the list, it's more that expected. Instead of just having 2 here, I'm getting 5.

I'm ok with the mixin adding properties in the background, but if that's the case, I want to know a way to check declared properties.

For illustration, checkout the ***`test/mixin`*** branch of [my sample project in GitHub](https://github.com/psychopunch/bookstore-demo).

In particular, see the files:

- [`PropertyMixin.groovy`](https://github.com/psychopunch/bookstore-demo/blob/test/mixin/src/groovy/io/github/psychopunch/bookstore/PropertyMixin.groovy)
- [`PropertyMixinSpec.groovy`](https://github.com/psychopunch/bookstore-demo/blob/test/mixin/test/unit/io/github/psychopunch/bookstore/PropertyMixinSpec.groovy)

Comment: Your question and your code suggests that you are confused about how mixins work in Groovy.  Can you describe what properties are being added and which you expected to be added?

Comment: I don't expect properties to be added at all, just the method called `transform`. I don't know what the added properties are exactly, but they look like they're being added by the compiler.

Comment: What are the property names that you are surprised by?

Comment: Things like, `log`, `class`, `__timeStamp__239_neverHappen1402586467581`...

Comment: Those don't have anything to do with your mixin, do they?

Comment: I think those will be there even if you don't use a mixin.

Comment: Only `class` is there if there's no mixin.

Comment: That does not make sense.  There are a number of other properties that we add at compile time.

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/jeffbrown/9a873cce2acfd1561e3d

Comment: I don't know about that but if that's what you're expecting then wouldn't that break what [`Object#getProperties()`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#getProperties()) was meant to do?

Comment: No, it doesn't break `getProperties()`, which does what it is supposed to do.  It isn't clear to me what your real question is but if the only property that is being added to your class by the compiler when you don't use a mixin is `class`, as you said above, then something is wrong.  I suspect that is not the case.

Comment: You said that things like __timeStamp__239_neverHappen1402586467581 are added if you use a mixin and not added if you don't. That isn't really the case, is it?

Comment: That's what my unit tests indicate. It turns out there are many questions there: 1) Is getProperties() only meant to return declared properties? 2) Why does mixin seem to add those properties? 3) Why does getProperties expose those? I'm not very familiar with how things behave exactly in relation to these.

Comment: What is returned from `getProperties` and what is added by the compiler are not the same thing.  __timeStamp__239_neverHappen1402586467581 should not be showing up in `getProperties`.  If it is, something else is wrong.

Comment: That's what I want to know because that's not what I was expecting, too. I showed my set up so people can see anything irregular.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something early in the thread.  Apologies.  Let me probe for something specific and maybe that will lead to clarity.  Describe something that you are seeing when you apply the mixin which you do not see when you do not apply the mixin that surprises you and describe how you are discovering that thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55530/discussion-between-jeff-scott-brown-and-psycho-punch).